# Use dynamically created name in to_regclass() function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I have dynamically created table name and I need check this table existing, for this I do:

```
....
SELECT to_regclass('public.tableprefix_'||variable_name) INTO table_exists;
IF table_exists IS NULL THEN 
    RETURN 'NOT EXISTS';
ELSE
    RETURN 'EXISTS';
END IF;
....
```

This gives error `function to_regclass(text) does not exist`

Then I trying explicit type casts:

`SELECT to_regclass('public.tableprefix_'||variable_name::regclass) INTO table_exists;`

But also same error, Where I am wrong? how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\df to_regclass

```
postgres=# \df to_regclass 
                              List of functions
┌────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────┐
│   Schema   │    Name     │ Result data type │ Argument data types │  Type  │
├────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────┤
│ pg_catalog │ to_regclass │ regclass         │ cstring             │ normal │
└────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────┘
(1 row)
```

you have to use cast to `cstring`

Comment: `SELECT to_regclass('public.tableprefix_'||variable_name::cstring) INTO table_exists;` this is right way? this gives also same error

Comment: it should work, although the name of target variable is wrong and then your code will be less readable. I would to use for this purpose some like "tableoid". Maybe you should to use parenthesis `to_regclass(('xxx' || var)::cstring)`

Answer (score 1):

An another way

```
 declare 
table_exists boolean;

begin

select EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
        AND table_name = 'tableprefix_' || variable_name || ''
    ) into table_exists;

If  table_exists =true then
RETURN ' EXISTS';
else
RETURN 'NOT EXISTS';
end IF;

end
```

Comment: This works fine, I am just trying first version, cos its  short. if this "short way"  does not work, I've use your version